# WPF/C#: 'Slide to Unlock' feature from iPhone

Tags: iphone, wpf, mocking

I just want to ask for your opinion on how to achieve the 'Slide to Unlock' feature from iPhone using Windows Presentation Foundation.

I already came across to this article: [iPhone slide to unlock progress bar (part 1)](http://www.garrettgirod.com/?p=19), and wondering if you can give me some other resources for a good head start. Thank you.

Comment: You want the iPhone style slide to unlock on a **windows** app in WPF?

Comment: @giddy: Just a WPF page/window would do.

Comment: Be careful that you don't infringe on [Apple's patents](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2010/08/17/ios-slide-to-unlock-is-now-an-apple-patent/)

Comment: @Gareth: Does Apple's patents work 'worldwide'? I mean, I'm from overseas. Lol.

Comment: @Gareth: Besides, Android also implemented something similar with Apple's

Comment: Android would either have made it different enough not to infringe (and they would have had lawyers make sure of that), or they might have paid Apple to be able to use it. I'm guessing you haven't done either of those things ;)

Comment: If patents didn't work worldwide they wouldn't really be effective.

Comment: Android's slide feature is oriented vertically and looks considerably different.  100% of the screen real estate that the slider uses is the hotspot, and so the fact that it uses more screen space than Apple's is mitigated by its being easier to use.  It's a superior design for a lot of other reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would retemplate a Slider, as this is the closest control, functionality-wise.

You should catch the event of Value_Changed, and if Value == Maximum then the slider is "opened".

Retemplating the control would make it look like your "unlock control" with ease. I'll paste later an example.

-- EDIT -- 
Have free time at work, so I started it for you.
The usage is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Slider Margin="185,193,145,199" Style="{DynamicResource SliderStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

and the ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>


    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="SimpleScrollRepeatButtonStyle" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="ThumbStyle1" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid Width="54">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" />
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFBFB" Offset="0.075"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Gainsboro" Offset="0.491"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCECECE" Offset="0.509"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA6A6A6" Offset="0.943"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="14" Padding="4">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF252525" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5C5C5C" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot">
                        <TextBlock Text="Slide to unlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <!-- TickBar shows the ticks for Slider -->

                        <!-- The Track lays out the repeat buttons and thumb -->
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Height="Auto">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle1}"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SimpleScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" Background="Transparent"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SimpleScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft"/>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight"/>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>

                        <!-- Use a rotation to create a Vertical Slider form the default Horizontal -->
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridRoot">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <!-- Track rotates itself based on orientation so need to force it back -->
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note that this is a very good start, but it's not everything.
I would also define a custom control that derives from slider and that uses this style automatically. Also I would expose a SlideUnlocked event when the user slides all the way right. 
To finish it all i would also add an animation that moves the Thumb back left in case the user has dragged it right, but not all the way (to imitate iPhone's UX exactly.)

Good luck, and ask away if you don't know how to implement any of the stages i suggested.

Comment: Added style to make it look like iPhone's slider.

Comment: I'd retemplate the Checkbox, which is the control that visually represents two distinct states and provides a UI for changing from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

WPF slider has got one "-" and it is value ,
 always when you move it, value is for example in decimal 1,122213174 so one "-".
But another way to create slider is in Windows forms.

Create trackBar1 ,and maximum = 100 points.
This is for Windows forms application:
On trackBar1_mouse_up:

```
if(trackBar1.Value < 100) 
  { 
    //Animation - slide back dynamicaly.

   for(int i=0;i<=trackBar1.Value;i++){
      int secondVal=trackBar1.Value-i;
      trackBar1.Value=secondVal;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
   }
 }
 if(trackBar1.Value==100) 
 {
    //sets enabled to false, then after load cannot move it.
    trackBar1.Enabled=false;
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
 }
```

And this for WPF Slider: (on PreviewMouseUp)

```
  if (Convert.ToInt16(slider1.Value) < 99)
        {
            //Animation - slide back dynamicaly.

            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(slider1.Value); i++)
            {
                int secondVal = Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value) - i;
                slider1.Value = secondVal;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                if (secondVal < 2)
                {
                    slider1.Value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt16(slider1.Value) > 99)
        {
            //sets enabled to false, then after load cannot move it.
            slider1.IsEnabled = false;
            slider1.Value = 100;
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }
```

Good luck! I hope it helps, try it with slider, but I think application will crash.